# PhaserJS: Issue with sprite animation

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a small issue that and I’m not able to figure out what’s wrong, maybe someone can help.

It seems player.anims.play(‘walk’) is not working I get an error which reads “Cannot read property ‘frame’ of undefined”.

It seems I get an empty array of frames.

How I load my spreadsheet in preload():

```js
this.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/characters.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 })
```

How my class looks :

```js
export default class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number) {
    super(scene, x, y, 'player')
    const player = scene.physics.add.sprite(x, y, 'player')
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true).setInteractive()

    scene.anims.create({
      key: 'walk',
      frames: scene.anims.generateFrameNames('player', { start: 1, end: 3 }),
      repeat: -1
    })

    player.anims.play('walk')
  }
}
```

in create():

```js
this.player = new Player(this, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Found the solution myself I’m using Phaser 3.21.0 and it seems that inside this.load.spritesheet I have to pass endFrame inside config object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution I’m using Phaser 3.21.0 and it seems that inside `this.load.spritesheet` I have to pass endFrame inside config object